# show values on bars in bar charts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with column(C_NC) containing two values namely C and NC. I plotted frequency of C and NC values with

```
df['C_NC'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Though this graph is nice, I also want to have exact frequency number on each bar in bar chart. I am quite new to Data visualization with Pandas Dataframe. Is there a way to do this with pandas dataframe?

Comment: You are welcome, tell me if it works: `s=df['C_NC'].value_counts()` and then 
`s.plot(kind='bar',yticks=s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
s=df['C_NC'].value_counts()
s.plot(kind='bar',yticks=s)
```

**Example**

as you can see here is the same problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
s1=pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,2,300))
s=s1.value_counts()
print(s)


1    156
0    144
dtype: int64
```

---

```
s1.value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

---

**we can now show the exact values**

```
s.plot(kind='bar',yticks=s)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @ansev...This certainly would help.....I am just curious if there Is a way through which we can preserve earlier y range as well?

Comment: You are welcome, I think this could create a graph with an inconsistent scale